# How to correctly read CSV file, BLOB not UTF-8 string

Tags: apex

I have a CSV file which I am trying to read using Apex, the file looks like this:

```
COLUMN1;COLUMN2;COLUMN3;COLUMN4;COLUMN5;COLUMN6;COLUMN7
VALUE1;VALUE2;VALUE3;VALUE4;VALUE5;VALUE6;VALUE7;
```

The file is stored as an attachment which I query like this and try to read:

```
Attachment csvFile = [SELECT Body FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId =: myFileId LIMIT 1];
String csvContent = csvFile.Body.toString();
```

> This returns BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string

I've also tried encoding it like this:

```
Blob csvBlob = csvFile.Body;
String csvContent = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(csvBlob);
```

But this brings back random characters in the `csvContent` variable, likely because its been encoded.

Can anyone advise the correct way to "decode" this?

Comment: Hello!
I am facing a similar difficulty... I think there's a big problem with the way that the CSV files are converted to Blobs.
Did you find out a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the bytes you shared, the text came out as:

```
STAMP_DATE;CUSNO;FIRSTNAME;LASTNAME;COMPANYNAME;ROWTEXT1;ROWTEXT2;ROWTEXT3;CUSTOMER_TYPE;CUSTOMER_TITLE;CUS
```

Which means that the problem isn't at the beginning. What's going on is that you've got a stray byte somewhere that isn't UTF-8 compatible, and the upper range of ASCII characters (0x80-0xFF) have a different meaning in Unicode (mostly invalid combinations, like 0x80 0x00 would be invalid).

Without seeing the entire file, we really have no idea what's broken, but if I had to guess, it's most likely a character that has some sort of decoration (e.g. Ñ), which in ASCII are one byte, but in Unicode are two (or more) bytes. When invalid characters appear in a Unicode string, Apex code fails with that exception, as it cannot understand ASCII/ISO-8859-1 encoding except in some special circumstances.

If your file is in ISO-8859-1 format, you'll first need to convert it to be Unicode compliant. Most likely, that means opening it up in a text editor (not Notepad, but a good one, like Programmer's Notepad or Notepad++), change the encoding to Unicode, upload the new file to Salesforce, and try again. Or, you can try to decode it using something like in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/223366). Your results may vary.